# postgresql delete rows based on inner join of complex subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to delete the matching rows from two complex subqueries. I am using postgresql. Here is a sample code:

```
DELETE FROM complex_subquery1 as a
USING   complex_subquery2 as b
WHERE a.column1 = b.column2
```

I read here: [PostgreSQL: delete rows returned by subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660142/postgresql-delete-rows-returned-by-subquery) that this is not really possible this way. Is there a shortcut for the case of deleting inner join?

Comment: Why don't you do it with CTE as in the linked answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do that is

```
DELETE FROM atable
USING complex_subquery1 as a,
      complex_subquery2 as b
WHERE a.column1 = b.column2
  AND a.column3 = atable.column4;
```